# What part of speech is "down" in "Put your pencils down"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

I need to know what down in this specific sentence means. I don't know if it is a preposition or an adverb.

Comment: At the risk of being contradicted by the professional grammarians I would say it is an adverb, qualifying the verb *put*. One could also say *put down your pencils*. Or could *put down* be regarded as a composite verb?

Comment: Oh boy, you've really done it now!!! :)

Comment: @WS2 It depends on whether you mean to place your pencils on the table or whether you mean to disparage them.

Comment: @Araucaria this is the schroedinger's cat of grammar.

Comment: The same part of speech as "up" in "Put your hands up."

Comment: @HotLicks But probably not as in "I have to put up with the people who put up with me."

Comment: @deadrat - Up with that I will not put.

Comment: @HotLicks "Put up or shut up."  Not a challenge; just another (counter)example.

Comment: It's a particle, in the same way "off" is in the expression "take off."

Comment: One can note that, with expression of this form, one can usually reorder the words.  Eg, "Put down your pencils" or "Put up your hands".  When reordered, the words "down" and "up" are functioning as adverbs.  But this approach is less satisfying for "Put your hands in your pockets", as one would be unlikely to say "Put in your pockets your hands."  Yet "in your pockets" fills the same syntactic niche as "up".

Comment: @HotLicks But you might say *Put in your pockets anything currently lying on this half of the table, including the money, but excludingt the penknife and the foreign coins.*. The positioning of the adverbial clause *in your pockets* is principally determined by the length and complexity of that which follows.

Comment: @WS2 - I would be very unlikely to use that construction.  I'd more likely say "Take anything currently lying on this half of the table, including the money, but excluding the pocket knife and the foreign coins, and put it all in your pocket."

Comment: I like to call them Adverbial Particles, this is often used in [POS annotaion](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/histcorpora/annotation/pos-misc.htm#adverbial_particles).

Comment: This will be confusing because, strictly speaking, "Put your pencils down" is bad grammar, so you're asking "What is the name of this word, according to <some rules>, when it's used in a sentence which doesn't follow those rules"?  It's akin to saying "According to the rules of baseball, can a runner on fifth base steal a base?", the answer being "I can't really answer that because there is no fifth base according to the rules of baseball."

Comment: @MaxWilliams In what dialect is "Put your pencils down" bad grammar?

Comment: @StoneyB on further investigation, perhaps none.  I thought it was wrong to  split "put down" into different parts of the sentence, but maybe *i'm* wrong.

Comment: @deadrat In fact, the *put up* part appears to be *put X up* in the sense of *pocket, endure*, which for some reason evolved into *put up **with** X* around 1750. See [*OED 1*]() s.v. **put, 53 put up**, sense **p** *(a)* and *(b)*.

Answer (score 37):

You pays your money and you takes your choice:

- Traditional grammar calls it an *adverb*: a word which modifies words which are not nouns.
  —But *down* plays an obligatory role in this sentence; I see no sense in which it can be said to "modify" *put*.
- Some contemporary grammarians call it a *particle*:

  > a word that
  >    does not belong to one of the main classes of words
  >    is invariable in form, and
  >    typically has grammatical or pragmatic meaning.
  >       —[SIL Glossary of Linguistic Terms](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAParticle.htm)

  —In other words, *particle* is a box where we dump anything which doesn't belong anywhere else. (At one time *adverb* served this function, but that use is no longer chic.)
- Other modernists call it an *intransitive preposition*—essentially a word which can serve as a preposition phrase all by itself, without an object.

  —I like this. *Down* in your sentence behaves just like any other preposition phrase (*on the table*, *in your pockets*, *behind your ears*) would, as a complement to the verb *put* depicting the goal where the object of the verb ends up.

Comment: Good answer.  I up voted it.  But what about "clean up your room / clean your room up"?

Comment: @michael_timofeev That's a lot harder to sort out, because what we're dealing with is a figurative extension of *up* from clearly locative complement uses in collocations like *pick up*, *sweep up*  to an effectively adverbial sense in of something like "completely" in collocations like *eat up*, *tear up*. *Clean up* seems to lie somewhere in the middle. ... But I think the 'core' sense is still locative, and the syntactic function is still complementary -- so I'd stick with calling it a preposition. Prepositions are gnarly that way in practically all contexts.

Comment: I ask, because I get asked this often in the classroom and I usually call them particles.  "Up" is one that seems to be a particle often.  "Down" and "off" not so much.  I call them particles because they can move in the sentence and change the emphasis when they move.  Interestingly, if we replace "your pencils" with "that" it seems harder to say "Put down that."  It's certainly possible but seems more awkward than "Put that down."  So, I think calling it a preposition is better.

Comment: Speaking of "down" here's an example from ten minutes ago http://english.stackexchange.com/q/280968/129806

Comment: @michael_timofeev Yes, that's a nice one. *Down* there of course is pretty transparently locative: you put your bet *down* = on the table.

Comment: It's a good answer.  However, think about "down" being a modifier of a prepositional phrase, the PP itself being understood in the example, which means something like "Put your pencils down on your desks!"  A modifier of a PP would, I suppose, be an adverb (downstairs), but in this sentence, a PP (upstairs).

Comment: "Turn on the light." vs. "Walk on the rug." -- In the former, 'on' seems more closely tied to the verb than to the object. In the latter, rearrangement to "Walk the rug on" isn't satisfactory.

Comment: While "put your pencils down" is something of a set phrase, do you really see *down* as obligatory here [assuming I understand what you mean by obligatory]? You could also say "put your pencils away", "put your pencils over there", "put your pencils back in your desks",  etc.

Comment: I feel like I am missing the joke, but why did you use the term "you pays"? Is that some English SE meme?

Comment: Yes, "down" definitely is modifying "put", as "put down" and "put ... down" are common phrases. For example the phrase [You'd better put down the duckie if you want to play the saxaphone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UiQsaEdJ1aI). IMHO those are both the same part of speech (whatever you want to call it), and its the user's option whether to place their "down" before or after the object clause. And yes, @michael_timofeev 's "up" is the same kind of thing.

Comment: @ThePhoton *Down* itself is not obligatory, but it occupies an obligatory slot in the sentence. As far as I know the only thing that can be *put* without a locative is a *shot*, except in contexts where the locative is implicit in the situation: put a bid, put a question.

Comment: @MarchHo It's an old tag; I learned it from *Huckleberry Finn*, but it's said [here](http://www.nytimes.com/1988/02/28/magazine/on-language-you-pays-yer-money.html) to be of BrE origin.

Comment: There are major problems with the intransitive preposition analysis. 'Put your pencil here' is another directional particle; there is no prepositional for it to have been reduced from. 'The war was dreadful, but Europe slowly recovered after' can be seen as a reduced form, but 'We went down to the lake and walked round' introduces obvious difficulties. Being able to complement 'put' is only one property of typical PPs.

Comment: *in-transit*ive? Sounds like this phrase is... going places! *ba dum tss*

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *Here, there, thither &c* I take to be pro-PP. I see no difficulty with *down to* or *round*. *Down to* is paralleled in either stacked PP like *on Broadway at 7th* or double P like *into, off of, until*, depending on how you want to analyze it. *Round* is simply a variant of *around*. But if you want something problematic, how bout *home*? :)

Comment: We've covered why _home_ behaves like an adverbial here before. Where it does, it's a legacy of an inflected form of the noun, meaning [at home] or [to home]. //  I'm saying that justification for the intransitive preposition position often involves analogy with a true PP. 'We'll come after [the match etc].' But with 'We went down to the lake and walked round', there does not need to be the 'round it' interpretation. I think that locative and directional particles need their own class/es.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Bare *around* likewise is etymologically a PP, like *across* and *away*. I have no objection to a new term for locative/directive words, or l/d phrases either, for that matter; the old-fashioned mechanical analysis as "adverbs" is hopeless.

Comment: I'd agree in that I'm not happy about 'around' in 'walked around' being classed as a 'modifier' of the verb. But surely the central property of a preposition is distributional, in that it 'connects to' (attaches) a meaningful noun phrase. Other usages (eg _from_ under the bed) (where 'from' attaches a PP) are much rarer and can be seen as peripheral. Attaching nothing seems a gross overlumping.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Seems to me this is a difference in syntactic deployment, not in word-class (but I admit to a kind of antipathy to word-classes in English anyway). I don't see a different *around* being used in "walking around" and "walking around the garden" or "waking around midnight".

Comment: The cohesiveness between the different words is markedly different. 'Walking around' has a near MWV meaning. Compare 'peregrinate' = 
'travel or wander from place to place' [ODO] The particle modifies the meaning of the simplex verb (admittedly not as much as in many, unquestionable MWVs).{(http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/peregrinate)}. 'Walking [around the garden]' has a typical adverbial modification of a simplex verb. Walking [[at]] [around midnight] uses 'around' to broaden the  time interval specified. It needs to immediately precede 'midnight' and is tightly bound.

Comment: @michael_timofeev *But what about "clean up your room / clean your room up"?* "**Up**" in this sense implies "completely" and is somewhat emphatic.  Consider "He opened the box" - he might open the lid only slightly... but "He opened the box up" implies that he opened it completely. "He used up all the fuel." All this tends to point at "up/down, etc. as being adverbial in action.

Answer (score 5):

> **Put** your pencils **down**.

The example that you give makes use of a multi-word verb, a phenomenon that is especially common in the English language. According to the Cambridge dictionary, "down" in your sentence would be an adverb particle, the best of both worlds of StoneyB's response. In fact, "down" is on the list of the most common adverb particles.

Specifically, "put down" is a phrasal verb, a classification of multi-word verbs. Phrasal verbs commonly take objects, and in the given example, the object would be

> your pencil,

or more strictly speaking, the noun

> pencil

modified by the possessive adjective "your."

The Cambridge Dictionary gives a very similar example:

> **Take** your shoes **off**.

where the direct object

> your shoes

splits the main verb

> Take

and the adverb particle

> off

of the phrasal verb "take off."

Check out this link for more information on multi-word verbs: [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/verbs-multi-word-verbs).

Comment: I don't think this is a phrasal verb.  Phrasal verbs must modify the meaning of the verb they are attached to.  "Take" and "take off" is a good example... "off" completely changes the whole meaning of the verb.  "Put down (on the desk) is just "put the pencil downward (on the desk)".

Comment: See [Put Down](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/put-sth-sb-down). Do you have a source that indicates that phrasal verbs must modify meaning?

Comment: I invite you to look at [this](http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/easy/phrase.htm) page as an additional resource. It lists many usages of the phrasal verb "put down." Yes, phrasal verbs often take on many meanings, but they're not exclusively used to denote something different from the standalone verb.

Comment: Parsimony, and because if phrasal verbs didn't modify core meaning, they wouldn't need to be named something different other than "verb and adverb that often go together".  The sentence is completely explainable without resorting to "exotic" grammar concepts.

Comment: I maintain my position and respectfully disagree, and I challenge you to find a source that supports your position. I don't see phrasal verbs as an "exotic" grammar concept. In fact, phrasal verbs seem rather straightforward. They're well-defined by many reputable sources, and in all cases, whether meaning is modified or not, the terms "take off" and "put down" are comprised of a "verb and adverb that often go together." A phrasal verb is defined as exactly that; the only difference is that "phrasal verb" communicates the same thing in fewer words. To each his own.

Comment: I mean, if you want a cite, just go to the Wikipedia page for "phrasal verb".  It's the first sentence, and the first cite.  By "exotic" I mean "beyond grade-school level grammar".  There would be no need for the term "phrasal verb" if it weren't a distinct concept from verb + adjective.